# Set data frame column name to character string, ie switch character type to "programming language" type?

Tags: r

I don't know how to describe this question in the title very well. As an arbitrary example, I have created a function that creates a data frame of a vector, and its argument is supposed to be the column name of the new dataframe. However, when I run the function it returns "string" as the dataframe colname, instead of "character_string" as the colname. Pretty straightforward and I know whats happening, it's just I can't seem to find the right R function to help me achieve this.

```
func <- function(string){
  vec <- 1:5
  df <- data.frame(string = vec)
  return(df)
}

df <- func("character_string")
df
    string
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
```

Here is another example,

```
func2 <- function(statement){
  df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 5:10)
  flag <- FALSE
  if(statement){
    flag <- TRUE
  }
  return(flag)
}

func2("df[1,1] == 1")
```

This will obviously return an error, I need the `func2` to return the `flag` as `TRUE`. This may seem like a very weird way of doing something, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around this concept for some other application.

Comment: Hi Chris, nice example to start on Stackoverflow and welcome. Perhaps too simple to put a `names(df) <- string`, before `return(df)`, could handle more column names with `c(name1, name2...)`. Just a thought. I guess I'd ask you to expand a bit on the last part of the title, i.e. character type to program type.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for the response - it definitely solves this particular arbitrary example. I'm working on a project and I don't want to post the exact problem I'm confronted, because I'm afraid of getting hit by the "TL;DR" response. So I rather try to use a basic example thereof. I have another example that could potentially illustrate the last part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part of your question: You can use `setNames()` or `names(x) <- ""` to change the name of the `data.frame` after creation.

```r
func <- function(string){
  vec <- 1:5
  df <- data.frame(string = vec)
  setNames(df, string)
}

func("character_string")
#>   character_string
#> 1                1
#> 2                2
#> 3                3
#> 4                4
#> 5                5
```

The tidyverse allows you to use the value of the function argument as a name for the variable, at the time of creation. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) for more info on that.

```r
library(tidyverse)
func_b <- function(string){
  vec <- 1:5
  tibble({{string}} := vec)
}

func_b("character_string")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   character_string
#>              <int>
#> 1                1
#> 2                2
#> 3                3
#> 4                4
#> 5                5
```

Second part of your question: A combination of `eval()` and `parse()` allows you to evaluate a condition that is supplied as a text string.

```r
func2 <- function(statement){
  df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
  eval(parse(text = statement))
}

func2("df[1,1] == 1")
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you want to call a function on a comparison statement and ensure that the statement is evaluated against the function environment, meaning: you don’t put quotations around the comparison statement, use `substiture()` and `eval()` as follows.

```r
func2_b <- function(statement){
  df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
  eval(substitute(statement))
}

func2_b(df[1,1] == 1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive feedback, this is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: That's good to know! Please consider marking my answer as the correct answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: Will do. Sorry it's my first post on Stack, still need to learn the ropes.